# Flutter authentication using Fingerprint/FaceID

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to allow users to login into the app using Fingerprint(android)/FaceID(iOS). **But I need the user's fingerprint value to store it in my DB**. In local_auth I can authenticate using fingerprint/faceId that are stored in the user's phone. But I want to control this. Users have to give their fingerprint/faceID and further, we'll authenticate user by using their fingerprint/faceId value.

Is there any way to get response data for fingerprint/faceId? Need suggestion...

Comment: There is no identity associated with biometric authentication. It is simply a true/false did the authentication pass. Your app is responsible for creating an account if required using some identifier. If your app is purely on-device (ie no server) then you don't need an account identifier because there is only one account, so you can simply use the biometric to unlock the app. Perhaps if you edit your question to provide more detail on how your app works we can offer more detail

Comment: @Paulw11 User will set their fingerprint into our app first time and then they could login using their fingerprint/FaceId. We want to store their information into our DB and match for further verification.

Comment: That's not how it works.  You can't get any fingerprint or face data for privacy reasons.  It isn't a "login" system, it is an "owner authentication system". It tells you whether the device "owner" (Someone whose biometrics are registered on the device or who knows the passcode) was able to authenticate.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/